# Force Web App Install Banner in Chrome

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, service-worker

I've been trying out the example in the doc (https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/app-install-banner/basic-banner/index.html) but don't seem to be able to trigger the "add to homepage" banner.

Is there a way of defining and manually triggering it? or building a popup to perform a similar action?

In the perfect world, i'd want the same popup to work for both ios and android.

Answer (score 0):

Requirements has changed to display the "Add to homepage" banner.
You need to have:

- a name and a short_name
- an image sized 192x192
- a service worker to make some stuff offline

You need to define an empty service worker like this:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
});
```